# Prove that the number of $n$-digit binary numbers with exactly $k$ $1$s equals the number of $k$-subsets of $[n]$.

Tags: combinatorics, functions

> The number of $n$-digit binary numbers with exactly $k$ $1$s equals the number of $k$-subsets of $[n]$.

I think i'm on the right track, but I'm confused on how to write how it's onto and 1-1.
This is what I have so far.

Define: Let $A$ be all the $n$ digit binary numbers.
Let $B$ be the number of subsets of $n$. Define $f$ where the number of $n$ digit binary numbers with exactly $k$ $1$s is equal to the number of $k$ subsets of $n$.

Comment: Following paper might help: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.05794.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Assign to an $n$-digit binary number $b$ the subset
$$
A_b :=\{\,i \in [n] : \text{the $i$-th digit of $b$ is $1$}\,\} \subseteq [n].
$$
Can you show this mapping is bijective?

---

**Examples:** Consider $n=5$. The digits will be numbered from right to left, so $00011$ has a $1$ at the digits $1$ and $2$. Some subsets of $[5]$ obtained as mentioned above are
\begin{align}
A_{00011} &= \{ 1, 2\}, \\
A_{10101} &= \{ 1, 3, 5\}, \\
A_{11111} &= \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}, \\
A_{10000} &= \{ 5 \}.
\end{align}

Given different $5$-digit numbers $b\neq b'$, do we have $A_b\neq A_b'$? This would make the mapping injective.

Given any subset $A\subseteq [5]$, can we find a $5$-digit number $b$ such that $A=A_b$? This would make the mapping surjective.

Comment: Not sure if I really understand this. But let me explain what I think about the 1-1 function. If a1 and a2 were elements of A, How could it be explained that a1 and a2 can be mapped to the subset of s1,s2...sk where it would be a 1-1.

Comment: @Francis2618 Sorry but I don't get what you're asking. I added some examples and more precise questions to my answer though. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can map this problem to another more easy to understand (or probe). What you're looking for is the All Possible k Combinations of n numbers. Lets say for example that n = 5, and that k = 2. Picture the number 11111, in order to get all the posible numbers with two "1", you have to know in how many ways you can take 3 "1" away from the number 11111 and replace them with "0".

Sorry if I had a bad english :P but I hope it helps you.